# Abrir relatorio jasper reports no Servidor Web

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jasper-reports

Não consigo abrir meus relatorios no Servidor Web, apos deploy.

Meu projeto é java hibernate com maven.

Quando tento imprimir um relatório recebo este log do tomcat:

> Log do Tomcat

```
19-Aug-2017 20:35:32.050 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-10] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:260)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:104)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:72)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:60)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:201)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:216)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:85)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:286)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:759)
at br.com.emporio.financeirocasatua.bean.DespesaBean.imprimirOutros(DespesaBean.java:1571)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
... 33 more

19-Aug-2017 20:35:32.060 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:104)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:72)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:60)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:201)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:216)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:85)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:286)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:759)
at br.com.emporio.financeirocasatua.bean.DespesaBean.imprimirOutros(DespesaBean.java:1571)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> Meu codigo para chamar o relatório:

```
public void imprimirOutros() {

    try {

        if (filtro.getDataEntradaInicial() == null || filtro.getDataEntradaFinal() == null) {
            Messages.addGlobalInfo("Favor preencher os campos");
            return;
        } else {

            String recDataEntradaInicial = filtro.getDataEntradaInicialFormatada();
            String recDataEntradaFinal = filtro.getDataEntradaFinalFormatada();

            HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            parametros.put("DESPESA_DATA_ENTR_INICIAL", recDataEntradaInicial);
            parametros.put("DESPESA_DATA_ENTR_FINAL", recDataEntradaFinal);

            String caminho = null;
            switch (filtro.getRelatorio()) {
            case ("Nota Sem Boleto"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_NotaSemBoleto.jasper");
                break;
            case ("Vale"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_Vale.jasper");
                break;
            case ("Transferencia"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_Transferencia.jasper");
                break;
            case ("Bonificacao"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_Bonificacao.jasper");
                break;
            case ("Sistema Tributario"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_SistemaTributario.jasper");
                break;
            case ("Cheque"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_Cheque.jasper");
                break;
            case ("Datas Divergentes"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_DatasDivergentes.jasper");
                break;
            case ("X1"):
                caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/Despesa_X1.jasper");
                break;
            default:
                caminho = "Este tipo de relatorio não existe";
                break;
            }

            Connection conexao = HibernateUtil.getConexao();

            JasperPrint jpPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminho, parametros, conexao);
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jpPrint, false);
            jv.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (JRException erro) {
        Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar gerar o relatório Outros");
        erro.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o [Troubleshooting](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/error-when-running-reports-could-not-initialize-class) do JasperReport:

> This error is normally associated with a JVM not being started on a Linux machine in AWT headless mode. JasperReports Server doesn’t provide a virtual X frame buffer on Linux. To prevent Java from trying to connect to an X-Server for image processing in JRS [...]

E ele pede que primeiro você tente modificar seu script de inicialização do servidor incluíndo o seguinte JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

[Neste tópico no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property) um usuário diz ter resolvido o problema de forma semelhante à apontada acima, só que no código Java, através da configuração uma propriedade do sistema na inicialização.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Já neste [outro tópico](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825173/could-not-initialize-class-netsfjasperreportsengineutiljrstyledtextparser) o usuário diz ter resolvido adicionando o [`xml-apis`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis) como dependência.

Outras causas possíveis, segundo a comunidade são:

- Por alguma razão um ou mais jars estão faltando na instalação do Servidor JasperReports (Os jars abaixo são considerados o mínimo);

> Jasperreports-X.X.X.jar (Versão atual 6.4.1)
>    commons-digester-X.X.jar (Versão atual 2.1)
>    commons-collections-X.X.jar (Versão atual 3.2.2)
>    commons-javaflow-20160505.jar
>    commons-logging-X.X.X.jar (Versão atual 1.1.1)
>    commons-beanutils-X.X.X.jar (Versão atual 1.9.3)
>    iText-2.1.7.jsX.jar (usado para exportação de pdf versão atual 2.1.7.js6)

- Uma ou mais fontes padrões do sistema não estão disponíveis no ambiente.

A causa desse problema não é muito clara (como muitas coisas que envolvem o jasperreports) então se nada der certo tente uma das soluções propostas nesta [thread no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998762/could-not-initialize-class-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-util-jrstyledtextparser) com várias soluções apontadas pelos usuários.

Comment: Obrigado Gustavo por responder.

Comment: Vou testar com estas opções que você colocou e volto com o resultado.